# Getting error in select2 make dropdown selected using text error Uncaught TypeError: d[b] is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, jquery-select2

I have a dropdown as follows:

```
<select id="lang" >
    <option value="php">php</option>
    <option value="asp">asp</option>
    <option value="java">java</option>
</select>
```

I am using select2. I want to make the dropdown item selected using text rather than using value.

What I did is as follows;

```
$("#lang").select2();
$("#lang").select2('text','asp');
```

I am getting an error as follows:

```
select2.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: d[b] is not a function
```

I have tried to make a fiddle. [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/o0uxjjtq/249/)

Comment: Make sure of select2 version you are using.

Comment: I want the code head part in the html. how to you include the script?

Comment: @ Sudharsan S check the fiddle. All the other things using select2 working. The fiddle will give you a clear idea about what I need

Comment: @Sudharsan S FIDDLE not working as I needed, check the scenario correctly before reply buddy.check it nanpa.

Answer (score 0):

Finally after lot of research I got the solution as:

```
$('#lang :selected').text('asp').trigger("change");
```

It will solve the issue. [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/o0uxjjtq/252/)